Memberstack to Xano api communication
If I have a backend with endpoint named AddUserTokens and it is currently set to be public, but I want to change it in a way that only Memberstack can make request to this endpoint, furthermore this requests will be sent only if user will pay for a plan (new one or recurring one) and it will add tokens for user to spend (so you can clearly see why i dont want it to be public and modified by any user, only by memberstack after certain action which i have described above), how do i achieve that?
Should I set in Xano endpoint to public and add some middleware to catch out the headers or something similiar that will only authorize Memberstack request? After user pays for the plan this request must be authorized in Xano for the specific user, but Xano will only take it if its valid request from memberstack and then add tokens for the specified user.
